# Wix reboot creates uninstall even though install is not completed

Tags: .net, wix, setup-project

I am very new to wix and windows installer

My installer needs .net 4.7.2 as prerequisite. So the I added this as a prerequisite and wix restarts the computer. After the restart the installation continues, but my BootstrapperApplication checks some other prerequisite conditions and prevents installation.

But I can see the still see uninstall option in the control panel even though nothing is installed.

How do I prevent creation of uninstall?

Comment: I haven't faced this particular problem, but the first question is why your setup didn't refuse to install on first launch given the other, missing prerequisite condition? I would exit early if success is not possible.

Comment: Because my BootstrapperApplication is in 4.7.2 so it can't run until 4.7.2 is installed